# Error with trying to Tokenize text in Keras?

Tags: python, numpy, keras

Very new to Keras and deep learning but I am following a guide online and I am trying to tokenize my text so that I can access the "shape" to use as the "input_shape" as I create the layers for the neural network. Here is my code so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv(pathname, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
df = df[['content_cleaned', 'meaningful']]
df = df.sample(frac=1)

#Transposed columns into numpy arrays 
X = np.asarray(df[['content_cleaned']])
y = np.asarray(df[['meaningful']])

#Split into training and testing set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=21) 

# Create tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=100) #No row has more than 100 words.

#Tokenize the predictors (text)
X_train = np.concatenate(tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(int(X_train), mode="binary"))
X_test = np.concatenate(tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(int(X_test), mode="binary"))

#Convert the labels to the binary
encoder = LabelBinarizer()
encoder.fit(y_train) 
y_train = encoder.transform(y_train)
y_test = encoder.transform(y_test)
```

The error is highlighting:

```
X_train = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(int(X_train), mode="binary")
```

The error message is:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Can anyone catch my mistake and possibly provide a solution to this? I am quite new to this and haven't been able to work around this issue.

I want to be able to call "X_train.shape" so I can feed this into the input_shape when I create the layers for the network.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to convert a numpy array into a python integer, which is of course not possible and gives you the error (the error is unrelated to Keras). What you really want to do is to change the `dtype` of that numpy array to `int`. Try the following:

`X_train.astype(np.int32)`

instead of `int(X_train)`

Comment: Thanks for getting back. When I change this, I am prompted with this error: "invalid literal for int() with base 10." My naïve assumption would be that there is actual floats in the text that could cause this issue?

Comment: Yes, so it seems.

Comment: I did some more research, and it seems as if it could be an issue where there are spaces in the text that I am trying to convert into integers (which doesn't make much sense). Do you have any advice as to how to move forward with this? Looking at examples online etc they are using the IMDB or the Reuters datasets which I believe are already preprocessed more or less.

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like. What's in `df[['content_cleaned']]`? Perhaps it's appropriate to open a separate question for this?

Comment: Sorry forgot to include this. df[[‘content_cleaned’]] is the text. The other column is the binary target variable. I can make a new post if needed just let me know.